# From DocuSign REST API, how can I remove/delete a template completely

Tags: docusignapi

I'm having a look at the **DocuSign eSignature** REST API and in the Templates category it clearly states that

> "You can: Create, list, get, update, and delete templates"

but when I had a look at the list of available methods deleting a template wasn't there.

I have tried sending a DELETE request to `/v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}` but no luck.

Can anyone confirm if this is even possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete directly, instead you will move the template to `Deleted/Recyclebin` Folder and DocuSign will delete it permanently after sometime from the Deleted folder. To move the template to Deleted folder, you need to make below call:

**URI:**

```
PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/folders/recyclebin
```

**Body:**

```
{"envelopeIds":["templateId"]}
```

Body is having `envelopeIds`, but value of this will be your array of templateIds which you need to move to `Deleted` folder.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help :)