# DocuSign delete template method

Tags: docusignapi

Is ther ability to delete template using DocuSign API or move in recyclebin???
No information about it in docs. Read smth about deleting templates using dete envelop endpoint.

Useless: [From DocuSign REST API, how can I remove/delete a template completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50147187/from-docusign-rest-api-how-can-i-remove-delete-a-template-completely)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Maybe will be useful for somebody:

- https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/folders/folders/moveenvelopes/
- https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-node-client/blob/8304f9ff135d1660b8c773f02b2278dd7e501a08/test/FoldersApiIntegrationTestsWithCallback.js#LL105C4-L105C4